# Convert GTK# Color to System.Drawing.Color

Tags: c#, colors, mono, gtk, gtk#

Im trying to convert the color chosen from GTk# color dialog to system.Drawing.Color.
I have tried `System.Drawing.Color.fromargb(mygtkcolor.Red,mygtkColor.Green,mygtkColor.Blue);`

mygtkColor class is http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=T%3aGdk.Color

But it shows an error saying value of the color components should be less than 255.

Also tried `System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.fromHtml(mygtkColor.getHashValue().ToString());`

This time there is no error but the color is displayed is not correct.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: What’s the full name of `mygtkcolor`’s type?

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with GTK but what is its colour boundary (i.e 255)? you either need to use `min(x, 255)` or convert it to its representation in 255 (`x/maxcolor * 255`)

Comment: If it’s https://developer.gnome.org/pygtk/stable/class-gdkcolor.html, `mygtkcolor.Red / 65535 * 255`, I suppose.

Comment: @U2744SNOWFLAKE Its http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=T%3aGdk.Color.I think the one you have linked is the same.

Comment: @Sayse Like im getting the value 27091 for mygtkcolor.Red.So the error is 'red' should be >= 0 and <= 255

Comment: @techno - Snowflake's second comment has the solution then (except it needs to divide by a float)

Comment: @U2744SNOWFLAKE How did you get that,can you add it as an answer with more details?

Comment: @Sayse Not tried it,would like more details  though.

Comment: @U2744SNOWFLAKE Does not work,tried converting the float to int too.Shows wrong color

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If U2744SNOWFLAKE wishes to add an answer to this respect then I'll gladly delete,

Basically what you need to do is convert your number into a number that is an equal fraction in terms of `255` rather than `65535`

at the minute you have `27091/65535`.

By doing the division in this fraction you get its equivalent decimal, by multiplying this out by 255 you then receive the fraction in terms of 255

hence

```
(colorValue / 65535.0) * 255
```

<sub>This may need converting to integer</sub>

<kbd>[IDEONE example](http://ideone.com/GBarO5)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks but Does not work,tried converting the float to int too.Shows wrong color

Comment: @techno - You have done this for all three elements of the color? Is it far off? remember there will be less range with a color with a smaller range - As a secondary check you can reverse the check to see what number you receive back (`num/255.0 * 65535`)

Comment: Yeah ccolor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb ((int)tempcolor.Red/65535*255, (int)tempcolor.Green/65535*255,(int) tempcolor.Blue/65535*255);

Comment: @techno - that is doing integer division, see the code line in my answer, you need to divide by a float/double otherwise I'd imagine that is just (0, 0, 0)

Comment: Thanks a lot.Tried this double r = (tempcolor.Red / 65535.0) * 255;
  double g=(tempcolor.Green/65535.0)*255; 
  double b=(tempcolor.Blue/65535.0)*255;
  ccolor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb ((int)r, (int)g,(int) b);                   and it works :)